# How to filter columns based on specific values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm having a specific trouble of knowing how to filter values in a set of columns based on certain criteria in pandas df.

I have three columns with binary values in each 'yes/no'. I want to write a code that does the following:

Filter and keep ONLY rows that fulfill minimum of ONE 'yes' but maximum of ONE 'yes'.

So a row that shows: `"c1: YES, c2: no: c3: YES"` should be excluded.
A row that shows: `"c1: no, c2: no, c3: YES"` should be included.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can count if there is only on `yes` value by compare all columns with `sum` and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df.eq('yes').sum(axis=1).eq(1)]
```

Or:

```
df1 = df[(df == 'yes').sum(axis=1) == 1]
```